# Most efficient way to determine if an element is in a list

Tags: python

So I have `alist = [2,4,5,6,9,10]`, and `b = 6`. What is the more efficient way to determine if `b` is in `alist`?

(1)

```
if b in alist:
      print " b is in alist"
```

(2)

```
def split_list(alist,b):
       midpoint = len(alist)/2
       if b<=alist[midpoint]:
          alist =alist[:midpoint]:
          split_list(alist,b)
       else:
          alist=alist[midPoint:]
          split_list(alist,b)
```

I thought method number 1 is better because it is only one line of code, but I've read that method 2 is better because it searchs from middle of list rather than from the beginning the.

Comment: since its sorted binary search is a little faster ... that said it depends on the size of list also ... bigger lists will have bigger benefits ... you could easily do an experiment with the `timeit` module (although the fastest would be to use a set instead of a list ... , but if you need to convert it you will probably lose your speed up)

Comment: is `alist` always sorted?

Comment: method 2 assumes a sorted array. If your data size matters use a `set`

Comment: You can yourself check this easilywith the time module in python. [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)

Comment: yes alist is always sorted

Comment: @manuzi1 its bad form to use time.time() to profile code ...  instead timeit is much better ...

Comment: @PeterChao look at the `bisect` module instead of writing your own recursive binary search

Comment: The answer is "it depends". For the list you've given, I'll wager that (1) is faster than (2). For a significantly longer list, (2) might be faster.

Comment: @ForceBru nope - it uses a linear scan - nothing clever. The performance will vary on the length of the list and how soon (if ever) the value is found.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Of course, you are right. For some reasons i cannot edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the difference between the functions you have shown lies in the matter of time saving during execution. If you are sure that your list will always have more than 2 members then function 2 is better but not too much.

Here is how it works

Function 1

```
    if b in alist:
  print " b is in alist"
```

This will loop through all element in the list only looking for b and when it finds it makes it true but what if your list has 200 members times become sensitive for your program

Function 2

```
    def split_list(alist,b):
   midpoint = len(alist)/2
   if b<=alist[midpoint]:
      alist =alist[:midpoint]:
      split_list(alist,b)
   else:
      alist=alist[midPoint:]
      split_list(alist,b)
```

This does the same except now you are testing a condition first using that midpoint so as to know where might "b" be so as to save the task of looping through the whole list now you will loop half the time, 
Note:You will make sure that your list has much members may be more than 3 to be reasonable to do that remainder because it may make your logic easy and readable in the future.
 So in some way it has helped you but consider the fact that what if your list has 200 elements and you divide that by two will it be too helpful to divide it by two and use 100 loop?
No!It still take significant time!

My suggestion according to your case is that if you want to work with small lists your function 1 is better. But if you want to work with huge lists!! Here are some functions which will solve your problem will saving much of your time if you want the best performance for your program. This function uses some built in functions which does take small time to finish because of some list information are in already in memory

```
    def is_inside(alist,b):
        how_many=alist.count(b) #return the number of times x appears in the list
        if how_many==0:
           return False
        else:
           return True
        #you can also modify the function in case you want to check if an element appears more than once!
```

But if you don't want it to say how many times an element appears and only one satisfy your need! This also another way of doing so using some built in functions for lists

```
    def is_inside(alist,b):
        try:
            which_position=alist.index(b) #this methods throws an error if b is not in alist
            return True
        except Error:
            return False
```

So life becomes simple when using built functions specifically for lists. You should consider reading how to use lists well when they long for performance of the programs stuffs like dequeue,stacks,queue,sets

Good source is the documentation itself [Read here!](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 1):

The expected way to find something in a list in python is using the `in` keyword. If you have a very large dataset, then you should use a data structure that is designed for efficient lookup, such as a `set`. Then you can still do a find via `in`.

Comment: how does this address the question? (note that I dont think there is a valid answer that is SO acceptable for this question in its current form)

Comment: I re-read the question and I'll admit that his question is simply asking which is more efficient. And from that perspective this isn't a great answer. But I also think as a practical matter its important to realize that a) performance doesn't matter for his example, and b) if performance matters the best solution is a different data structure.